# Updated to PHP 7.2 on RHEL and getting frequent cURL errors 28: timed out before SSL handshake

Tags: php, curl, rhel

I upgraded my RHEL server (yum update) and updated php to 7.2 (ius) and enabled OPCache, now I'm getting intermittent CURL errors for timeouts from my webserver (apache) like:

```
cURL error 28: timed out before SSL handshake
```

for calls across different hosts.

Any ideas what is causing this or how I can track this bug down?

Comment: What happens when you do curl requests from bash or from the terminal ? Also I don't think, this question belongs here and should probably be asked in Server Fault

Comment: Only appears to happen through mod_php... ran a test script as CLi - no errors, ran it via the web - got errors. Sorry if this is in the wrong place.